# Reset JSessionID on URL modification

Tags: apache, jboss, load, load-balancing, jsessionid

I am currently Internationalising a website, and have hit some issues around the `jsessionID`s. I am using Apache web server that load balances across multiple JBoss app servers via mod_jk.

When I hit the site on the default GB URL, the jsessionID is correctly created on the dedicated jboss app server. e.g. `www.mysite.com` create session on `GB_Jboss`.

When I update the URL to `www.mysite.com/fr`, I want a new jsessionID to be created on `FR_JBoss`.

When I update the URL to `www.mysite.com/us`, I want a new jsessionID to be created on `US_JBoss`.

However, each time I update the URL, it always displays the original jsessionID.

I hope this makes sense? Any ideas how I can get this to work via Apache? Or id this a load balancing issue at the load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Curious to know why you want to have new session for different URI.  Anyway, couple of options I can think of:

1. Add an entry in the cookie for the URI you generated the session for.  For example, if **yoursite/fr** has got the session first, add that to the client cookie.  On each request, you can use filter to inspect whether the URI is different from the one specified in the cookie.  if yes, invalidate that session and let the new one be created for the user.
2. Maintain a singleton HashMap on the server side that has site URI and session ID mapping.  If the site URI does not match with session ID on each request - invalidate session.  The downside of this approach is that the HashMap needs to be replicated across all nodes in the cluster for it to work properly after a fail over to another server.

Comment: The reason I need a new session is because the site has a shopping basket. Each time the user switches the URI, a new session is required.

Your suggestions sounds as though I need to make a code change. Is there anything that can be done at the Apache level?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this on Apache.  I suggested solution that involve code changes since you mentioned you are in the middle of internationalizing your site.  Anyways, wondering if the user will switch often between URIs - coz if they do whatever implementation you choose, make sure that all orphans sessions are invalidated right away.  You don't want them to pile up fast to consume more memory and slow down data replication between your cluster nodes.